# Trying to find a odd shaped fan blade

Tags: ceiling-fan, fans

So we bought a new house and one of the fans had 1. ugly blades and 2. one blade was broken.

Naturally I took one good blade of and went to Lowes to find a replacement. It turns out though that this is some custom style of fan blade. I looked EVERYWHERE on this freaking fan and I can't find a brand name so I have no idea who to contact to get a new blade.

I'm curious if anyone can point me toward a source to find a new blade like the one in the picture

[image]

Comment: can you find blades with the same bolt pattern and replace all the bades on the fan.
On the other hand that looks like plywood, you could use it as a template and cut a new blade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the blade is a flat panel, no surface contour, you could either duplicate it yourself or find a wood shop or makerspace with members who might assist. It would be a simple matter to drop a panel into a laser cutter, cnc router, jig saw, band saw, so many options if you can identify the material from which it is constructed. Jasen's suggestion of replacing all three is a good one, as well. 3 mm or 6 mm plywood would be quite strong for this application and not particularly heavy. Our fans have veneer over particle board, cheap and heavier than ply.

Comment: probably want to replace all three blades, it's easier to get it balanced that way.

Comment: all six blades* 